# Creating document like this

Tags: packages, document-classes

I am trying to create a handout like the one in the following [link](http://www.courses.fas.harvard.edu/~math21a/homework/hw1.pdf).

Image:

[image]

But I can't get it. Can someone help me create such a document.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 13):

Here what I've done with the help of [Google](https://www.google.com) and [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com):

- used `geometry` package - for landscape orientation and margins;
- `enumitem` for inline enumerations and custom numbers for enumerations;
- `xcolor` for `\colorbox` and `\fcolorbox`.

**Result:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,twocolumn]{geometry}
    \geometry{left=5em}
    \geometry{top=5em}
    \geometry{right=5em}
    \geometry{bottom=5em}
    \geometry{columnsep=3em}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

{\footnotesize\textbf{Math 21a: Multivariable calculus\hfill Fall 2012}}\vskip 4ex

\colorbox{blue!10}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
        \Large\textbf{Homework 1: Geometry and Distance}
    \end{minipage}
}\vskip 3ex

{\footnotesize This homework is due Wednesday, 9/12 rsp Thursday 9/13.}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\colorbox{yellow!25}{\arabic*}]
    \item{}[Stewart 9.1: 8] Find the distance from $(3, 7, -5)$ to each of the following:

        \noindent
        \begin{enumerate*}[label=\alph*)]
            \item The xy-plan,
            \item the yz-plane,
            \item the xz-plane,
            \item the x-axes,
            \item the y-axes,
            \item the z-axes.
        \end{enumerate*}
    \item{}[Stewart 9.1: 14] Show that the equation represents a sphere and find its center and radius $x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} + 8x - 6y + 2z + 17 = 0$.
    \item{}[Stewart 9.1: 20] Find an equation of the largest sphere with center $(5, 4, 9)$ that is contained in the first octant.
    \item{}[Stewart 9.1: 28,30]
        \begin{enumerate}[start=28,label=\arabic*)]
            \item Describe in words the region $y^{2} + z^{2} = 16$ in $R^{3}$.
            \addtocounter{enumii}{1}
            \item Describe in words the region $y = z$ in $R^{3}$.
        \end{enumerate}
    \item{}[Stewart 9.1: 38] Consider the points $P$ such that the distance from $P$ to $A = (-1, 5, 3)$ is twice the distance from $P$ to $B = (6, 2, -2)$. Show that the set of all such points is a sphere and find its center and radius.
    \item{}(*) [Stewart 9.1: 42 not turned in] Describe and sketch a solid with the properties: When illuminated by rays parallel to the z-axis, its shadow is a circular disk. If the rays are parallel to the y-axis, its shadow is a square. If the rays are parallel to the $\mathrm{x}$-axes, its shadow is an isosceles triangle.
\end{enumerate}

\newpage

\colorbox{green!10}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
        \Large\textbf{Main deﬁnitions}
    \end{minipage}
}\vskip 4ex

\fcolorbox{red}{red!10}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
        A point in the \textbf{plane} has two \textbf{coordinates} $P = (x, y)$. A point in \textbf{space} is determined by three coordinates $P = (x, y, z)$. The signs of the coordinates deﬁne 4 \textbf{quadrants} in the plane and 8 \textbf{octants} in space. These regions by intersect at the origin $O = (0, 0)$ or $O = (0, 0, 0)$ and are separated by \textbf{coordinate axes} $\{y = 0\}$ and $\{x = 0\}$ or coordinate planes $\{x = 0\}$, $\{y = 0\}$, $\{z = 0\}$.
    \end{minipage}
}\vskip 2ex

\fcolorbox{red}{red!10}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
        The \textbf{Euclidean distance} between two points $P = (x, y, z)$ and $Q = (a, b, c)$ in space is defined as $d(P, Q) = \sqrt{(x - a)^{2} + (y - b)^{2} + (z - c)^{2}}$. The distance between a point $P$ and a geometric object $S$ like a line or plane is the minimal distance $d(P, Q)$ which is possible with $Q$ on $S$.
    \end{minipage}
}\vskip 2ex

\fcolorbox{red}{red!10}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
        A \textbf{circle} of radius $r$ centered at $P  =(a, b)$ is the collection of points in the plane which have distance $r$ from $P$. A \textbf{sphere} of radius $\rho$ centered at $P = (a, b, c)$ is the collection of points in space which have distance $\rho$ from $P$. The equation of a sphere is $(x - a)^{2} + (y - b)^{2} + (z - c)^{2} = \rho^{2}$.
    \end{minipage}
}\vskip 2ex

\fcolorbox{red}{red!10}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
        The \textbf{completion of the square} of an equation $x^{2} + bx + c = 0$ is the idea to add $(b/2)^{2} - c$ on both sides to get $(x + b/2)^{2} = (b/2)^{2} - c$. Solving for $x$ gives the solution $x = -b/2\pm\sqrt{(b/2)^{2} - c}$.
        \textbf{Example:} Find the center and radius of the circle $x^{2} + 8x + y^{2} = 9$. \textbf{Solution:} Add $16$ on both sides to get $x^{2} + 8x + 16 + y^{2} = 25$ which is $(x + 4)^{2} + y^{2} = 25$, a circle of radius $r = 5$ centered at $(-4, 0)$.
    \end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```